# How to write HQL for left outer join with criteria?

Tags: hql

I am new to Hibernate, can anybody correct the HQL for below SQL to find out the unique employees that are working to the client currently. if possible please provide me some links for tutorial.

while parsing the SQL I was able to receive some records from the database & also with Native SQL, but when I use below HQL I could not receive any records.

SQL :

```
select distinct u.employeeid from employee u 
    inner join address ad on u.employeeid = ad.employeeid
    left join company cp on (ad.oldcompanyid = cp.currentcompanyid and cp.wokingornot='Y')
    left join client cl on (ad.oldcompanyid = cl.currentcompanyid and cl.wokingornot='Y') 
    where (u.lastdate is null and ad.lastdate is null) 
          and (cp.wokingornot = 'Y' or cl.wokingornot = 'Y');
```

please correct the HQL listed below :

```
select distinct u from employee u ,address uo,company tp ,client mp  
inner join u.address uo 
left join uo.company tp   with tp.wokingornot= true  
left join uo.client mp with mp.wokingornot= true 
where (u.lastdate is null and uo.lastdate is null) 
and (tp.wokingornot= true or mp.wokingornot= true );
```

Below are the entities which I am looking for the HQL:

```
public class employee {
public Int employeeid ;
public set<address> address;
public Date lastdate;
public Date Startdate;
}

public class address{
public int addressid;
public int oldcompanyid;
public employee employee;
public Date lastdate;
public Date Startdate;
}

public class company{
public int currentcompanyid;
public string wokingornot;
public address address;
}

public class client{
public int currentcompanyid;
public string wokingornot;
public address address;
}
```

Comment: HQL queries are framed based on how entities are mapped. Posting the relevant entities will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to look more like this. You will get the whole object graph from the Employee class through Address down to Company and Client classes.

```
select distinct u from employee u
join u.address uo
left join uo.company tp
left join uo.client mp 
where u.lastdate is null and uo.lastdate is null
and (tp.wokingornot= true or mp.wokingornot= true )
```